Boolean Modifier - Why is the computation not working properly in the animation?
In this answer, it was explained how to get the surface intersection between a conical frustum and an ellipsoid.
In a static configuration, it works perfectly, as shown here

Now, I want to make the ellipsoid move, the frustum to orient and scale itself accordingly, and the intersection surface to be computed at each frame.
To do this, I first specify some ellipsoid positions at specified frames
ell_positions = [(2.5, 2.5, 2.5), (2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (4.0, 0.0, 4.0), (6.0, -2.0, 2.0), (8.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
frames = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80]
bpy.context.scene.frame_start = frames[0]
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = frames[-1]

I then place some keyframes
for frame, ell_position in zip(frames, ell_positions):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
    ell.location = ell_position
    ell.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location', frame = frame)

I then create a frame handler to animate the motion of the frustum and use it with
inter_mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "IntersectMat")
inter_mat.diffuse_color = (1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0)

def modify_fru_at_frame(scene, fru, r1, div, ell):
    frame: int = scene.frame_current
    cf = fru.location
    fru_direction = mathutils.Vector(ell.location) - cf
    fru_direction.normalize()
    up = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    fru.rotation_quaternion = up.rotation_difference(fru_direction)
    h = (ell.location - cf).length
    r2 = r1 + h * div
    fru.scale = (1.0, 1.0, h / fru.dimensions.z)
    fru.dimensions = (r2, r2, h)

def create_frame_change_handler_post(fru, r1, div, ell):
    @persistent
    def frame_change_handler_post(scene):
        modify_fru_at_frame(scene, fru, r1, div, ell)
    return frame_change_handler_post

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(create_frame_change_handler_post(fru = fru, r1 = r1, div = div, ell = ell))

This delivers the expected result.
If I now try to add the intersection computation at each frame, using
def get_surface_intersection(obj1, r1, div, obj2, inter_mat):
    obj1_copy = obj1.copy()
    obj1_copy.data = obj1_copy.data.copy()
    obj1_copy.name = "OBJ1_copy"

    obj2_copy = obj2.copy()
    obj2_copy.data = obj2_copy.data.copy()
    obj2_copy.name = "Intersection"

    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj1_copy)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj2_copy)

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    obj1_copy.select_set(True)
    obj2_copy.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj1_copy

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj2_copy
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = 'BOOLEAN')
    boolean_modifier = obj2_copy.modifiers[-1]
    boolean_modifier.operation = 'INTERSECT'
    boolean_modifier.object = obj1_copy

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = boolean_modifier.name)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj2_copy
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type = 'VERT')

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj2_copy.data)

    tol: float = 1.0e-3
    normal: mathutils.Vector = (obj2_copy.location - obj1_copy.location).normalized()
    ce = obj2.location
    h = (obj2.location - obj1.location).length
    r2 = r1 + h * div
    for vert in bm.verts:
        world_co = obj2_copy.matrix_world @ vert.co
        if np.abs((world_co - ce).length - r2) <= tol:
            if np.abs(normal.dot(world_co - ce)) <= tol:
                vert.select = True

    bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type = 'VERT')

    if obj2_copy.data.materials:
        obj2_copy.data.materials[0] = inter_mat    
    else:
        obj2_copy.data.materials.append(inter_mat)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj2_copy
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type = 'ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center = 'MEDIAN')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj2_copy.data)

    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj1_copy, do_unlink = True)

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

    return obj2_copy

def modify_intersect_surf_at_frame(scene, obj1, r1, div, obj2, inter_mat):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    intersect_obj = get_surface_intersection(obj1 = obj1, r1 = r1, div = div, obj2 = obj2, inter_mat = inter_mat)
    obj1_direction = obj2.location - obj1.location
    obj1_direction.normalize()
    up = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    intersect_obj.rotation_quaternion = up.rotation_difference(obj1_direction)


def create_frame_change_handler_pre(fru, r1, div, ell, inter_mat):
    @persistent
    def frame_change_handler_pre(scene):
        modify_intersect_surf_at_frame(scene = scene, obj1 = fru, r1 = r1, div = div, obj2 = ell, inter_mat = inter_mat)
    return frame_change_handler_pre

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(create_frame_change_handler_pre(fru = fru, r1 = r1, div = div, ell = ell, inter_mat = inter_mat))

what should recompute the intersection surface at each frame does not deliver the expected result. Why is that and how can I solve that issue?
